# Why is Spring Boot not rendering my view and instead showing a 404 error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I just started working with Spring Boot, and I'm trying to develop a very simple web application. I made a view to display a form and I'm trying to render it through a controller. However, when I open my page on localhost, it displays a Whitelabel Error Page with the error 404. I've looked for multiple things but I don't know where I went wrong.

This is my controller

```
package com.example.demo.user;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping
  public String index() {
    return "login";
  }

}
```

This is the main file

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And finally this is my view "login.html". It's located at src/main/resources/templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected this to work and I see no other error apart from the 404, and I don't know where I messed up. I thought it was okay but it clearly isn't. I'd like to know what I did wrong so I can correct it.

Comment: what url do you call? does it hit a breakpoint in index() at return "login";?

Comment: You would make providing you answers so much easier if you created a public GitHub repository with your complete, runnable test project.

Comment: 404 means the URL you used is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```